Find isomorphism of elliptic curves in Weierstrass form
I have the following two elliptic curves over an algebraically closed field of characteristic distinct from 2:
$$E:y^2=x^3+4x^2+2x\quad \quad E':y=x^3-8x^2+8x$$
I want to find an isomorphim $\psi:E'\rightarrow E$. I know that we have a 2-isogeny from $E'$ to $E$, but the kernel is not trivial since it contains both $O$ and $(0,0)$, so I must find a different map.
I have tried all my resources but none of them succeeded. I tried all maps of the form
$$(x,y)\longmapsto\left(\frac{x-a}{c^2},\frac{y}{c^3}\right)$$
i.e. I tried translations, rescaling and a combination of both. What I did is trying to put these new coordinates in the Weierstrass equation of $E'$ and solve for $a,c$ so that the equation would be the one of $E$. But I always got that not all conditions could be met simultaneously. I am desperate at this point, I feel like I have tried everything. Can someone help me please?

$E'$ is the quadratic twist of $E$ by $-2$, hence the curves are isomorphic over any field containing $\sqrt{-2}$. The map
\begin{align*}
E &\mapsto E'\\
(x,y) &\mapsto (-2 x, -2 \sqrt{-2} y)
\end{align*}
is an isomorphism.

Appreciated. I somehow managed to miss the part about the field being algebraically closed :-)

Thank you! You could also be sending $y$ to $2\sqrt{-2}y$, right? This would also obey the equation of $E$. Did you choose $-2\sqrt{-2}y$ for any particular reason?

Certainly, you can post-compose with the automorphism $(x,y) \mapsto (x,-y)$.
